# Use 192.168.0.0/16 or other iprange as pod cidr for kubernetes + flannel

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

In the tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/, it says

> For flannel to work correctly, you must pass `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` to `kubeadm init.`.

How to pass other cidr, e.g., `--pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the same steps in the tutorial, except:

(1) After `kubeadm reset`, clear earlier net interfaces on both master and slave nodes.

```
sudo ip link del cni0
sudo ip link del flannel.1
sudo systemctl restart network
```

(2) Run `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`

(3) Download the `kube-flannel.yml` file, change hard coded `10.244.0.0` to `192.168.0.0`, then do `kubectl create -f kube-flannel.yml`.

**Test result**

```
$ k get po -o=wide
NAME                         READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE
h2-75cb7756c6-r4gkj          1/1       Running   0          5m        192.168.1.14   slave1
h2-75cb7756c6-xfstk          1/1       Running   0          16m       192.168.0.5    master
jobserver-58bf6985f9-77mdd   1/1       Running   0          16m       192.168.0.6    master
jobserver-58bf6985f9-h9hlx   1/1       Running   0          5m        192.168.1.15   slave1

# ping pod on slave
$ ping 192.168.1.14  
PING 192.168.1.14 (192.168.1.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.454 ms

# ping pod on master
$ ping 192.168.0.5
PING 192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.143 ms

# ping docker container on the same node
$ ping 172.18.0.2    
PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=241 time=21.580 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Leon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52963103/4451944)

If you want to move your networking from `weavenet` to `flannel` the in Step 1 you also need to do `sudo ip link del weave`