# k8s & flannel --- dial tcp 172.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

1. i init kubeadm with follow command

> kubeadm init 
> --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.64.104 
> --image-repository registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers 
> --kubernetes-version v1.17.3 
> --service-cidr=172.96.0.0/16 
> --pod-network-cidr=172.244.0.0/16

2. i have one master and two node , i test follow command in three machine

> curl -k https://172.96.0.1:443/version

command result:

> ```
>  {
>   "major": "1",
>   "minor": "17",
>   "gitVersion": "v1.17.3",
>   "gitCommit": "06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213",
>   "gitTreeState": "clean",
>   "buildDate": "2020-02-11T18:07:13Z",
>   "goVersion": "go1.13.6",
>   "compiler": "gc",
>   "platform": "linux/amd64"
> }
> ```

3. but when i use command `helm install --namespace openebs --name openebs stable/openebs --version 1.5.0`, i get result is `Error: Get https://172.96.0.1:443/version?timeout=32s: dial tcp 172.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout`

i don't know what is happened now, and how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that **@wr1ttenyu zhao** has already resolved this issue, but I decided to provide an answer just for clarification.

As we can see in the [flannel documentation](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes.md#kubeadm):

> NOTE: If kubeadm is used, then pass --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 to kubeadm init to ensure that the podCIDR is set.

The [--pod-network-cidr](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options) option specifies range of IP addresses for the pod network.

We should use the `10.244.0.0/16` network because it's hardcoded in the [kube-flannel.yml](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) file:

```
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
    }
```

For this reason, creating a Kubernetes cluster with the `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` command will work with flannel without any additional flannel configuration.

To use a different network, we need to modify `"Network": "10.244.0.0/16"` line in the [kube-flannel.yml](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) file before applying it, similar to what is described in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52963103/14801225).

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem.

1. when i review my install process, i think this problem maybe associate with the step of apply follow command `kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml`
2. i find follow config code in my local kube-flannel.yml

> net-conf.json: | {   "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",   "Backend": {
> "Type": "vxlan"   } }

3. i think this ip maybe have to be same with `pod-network-cidr` parameter in kubeadm init command, so i reset k8s, and change my kubeadm init command like follow

> kubeadm init 
> --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.64.104 
> --image-repository registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers 
> --kubernetes-version v1.17.3 
> --service-cidr=10.96.0.0/16 
> --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

finally, it's works

4. although i solve this problem, i still don't figure it out what happen in this situation